# Rails: using custom skin with JWPLayer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jwplayer, skin

I have a question about using [JWPlayer](http://www.jwplayer.com) with Ruby on Rails. You can set custom skins by setting it as an option in the JWplayer options. You have to host these skins yourself and then state the path to the skin like: `skin: '/assets/skin.zip'` or something. But I can't figure out where in what format the custom skin should be placed? I've tried a lot of things like a `.zip` file directly in the assets folder. All these things gave me a `skin is not in the right format` error, even when I changed the path to the skin to something non-existent, so that's probably the default text when the skin cannot be loaded... Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using JW5 or JW6? In JW6, the skin should be XML, not ZIP.

Answer (score 1):

[Answer on your qeustion](https://github.com/vhyza/jw_player_helper)

You should put the skin into the right folder and define it without '.zip' extension in the end of the name of skin-file.

Answer (score 1):

Copy downloaded zip into `RAILS_ROOT/public/swf/skins` and set `:skin => 'name without .zip extension'` flashvar.

For Example:

```
<%= video_player({:file => "/video/pf2011.flv", :image => "/video/pf2011.jpg", :skin => "glow"}) %>
```

**[More Info](https://github.com/vhyza/jw_player_helper)**